# Keeping color from vim with grep

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, grep

I like the way vim highlights the output from syslog.  However, I only want the most recent outputs to be opened.  I tried

```
grep --color=always "$@" /var/log/syslog  > /tmp/fileOUT
vim /tmp/fileOUT
```

but it gives the bash color output like [033;m blah blah.  If I don't `include --color=always`, there is no color at all.  How can I do this?  (I'm using bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `vim` [uses color template files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127426/22222) for syntax highlighting. This has nothing to do with the output of `grep` which uses ANSI escape sequences (the `\[033;` stuff you mentioned).

My vim doesn't have a style file for syslog and does not color it (I checked both on Debian and on Ubuntu 14.04). If you look at the relevant file on your system, you will find it starts with a regular expression that defines the files to match against. So, if you make your `/tmp/fileOUT` match that syntax, it should be colored. Don't use `--color=always`, that will just screw things up.

Alternatively, you could use `source-highlight`. Install it with `sudo apt-get install source-highlight` and then run:

```
sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog | source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -s log
```

The command above will color the last 50 lines of `/var/log/syslog`:

[image]

Comment: Heck yeah!  Even better than having to type in the most recent time as a string (the "$@"), as my script was doing. Thanks.